# How to move Ubuntu from one disk to another while keeping windows (using clonezilla?)

Tags: partitioning, backup, migration

My current system drive is shared with windows and is running out of space. I have lots of programs installed and settings made in my Ubuntu system so I would really like to not have to re-install and reconfigure everything.

The goal is to

- Move all Ubuntu programs/settings/documents to a new drive and expanding old partitions to fill the new (bigger) drive.
- Keep Windows on the old drive
- Make both Windows and Ubuntu bootable again.

How do I do this the easiest way? Is it a stupid idea from the beginning ie. I should not do this, re-install is better? From what I've read [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) should be able to do the trick? But how? Are there any pitfalls here that I should be aware of?

df -h

```
/dev/sdc5          33G    31G   503M  99% /
udev              9,9G   4,0K   9,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs             4,0G   964K   4,0G   1% /run
none              5,0M      0   5,0M   0% /run/lock
none              9,9G   452K   9,9G   1% /run/shm
tmpfs             9,9G      0   9,9G   0% /tmpfs
/dev/sda3         300G   260G    41G  87% /media/Program
/dev/sdb1         230G   190G    41G  83% /media/Dokument
```

sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 huvuden, 63 sektorer/spår, 14593 cylindrar, totalt 234441648 sektorer
Enheter = sektorer av 1 · 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Diskidentifierare: 0xa8dc41c2

    Enhet Start     Början        Slut     Block    Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *        2048   156403807    78200880    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2       156405758   234440703    39017473    5  Utökad
/dev/sdc5       156405760   226093055    34843648   83  Linux
/dev/sdc6       226095104   234440703     4172800   82  Linux växling / Solaris
```

Comment: Although I don't have enough time to write a full answer right now, I can assure you that you're on the right track with **Clonezilla** and you just need to follow the right steps before and after, which you can easily find out or somebody might outline them here for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have never done it, but if I had to I would:

1. Setup a bootable CD / USB stick with [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). By moving systems around you're likely to break your boot, so boot-repair is a good thing to have in case you can't boot.
2. Make a full backup of the disk with clonezilla and store it somewhere secure (like an external hard drive that won't be connected during the following process). Make sure you have an image of the whole drive, not just the partitions.
3. Shut down, plug the new disk, boot normally and format your new disk as you want it.
4. Reboot on boot-repair.
5. From there, you have a pretty full-featured ubuntu, only with the addition of boot-repair. You can copy the system files from /dev/sdc5 to your new disk (let's say /dev/sdd1). **Important: use `cp -a` to get an exact copy of the system** (with symbolic links preserved and all). A normal copy (including through nautilus) would probably break a few things (and you would realize it only much later on).
6. Edit `/etc/fstab` and point `/` to `/dev/sdd1`
7. Execute boot-repair (I don't remember if it's on the desktop or the sidebar, or if it starts automatically... I only used it once or twice but I remember it was pretty obvious).
8. Boot-repair should recognize Windows and your 2 Ubuntus. You might want to edit your old system out. If the copy isn't seen at this point, you can still cancel everything, just restart normally, because you haven't modified your system yet (we just copied the files, not deleted them).
9. Reboot. If it didn't work, don't panic, boot on boot-repair again and try other settings. I had to do that a couple of times before it actually worked.
10. Reboot on Ubuntu, making sure you are on /dev/sdd1. Open Gparted, remove the old Linux and resize your Windows partition. Last time I did that it was with Vista, next time I booted on Windows I had to insert the installation CD to repair Windows, and then use boot-repair because it did override the bootloader. Maybe things improved since then, maybe not.

This should really work easily, although I never went through all these steps at once. If anything goes wrong before step 6, you still have your system intact. If anything goes wrong after that, you have a backup of your disk with clonezilla that you can restore. Although before step 9 you really still have your old system on which you can boot normally, which means you can check your system works before you erase it.

Long story short, whatever you choose to do, the only things that can (and will) happen is a broken boot that can be easily fixed by boot-repair.

PS: to answer on the usage of clonezilla, I wouldn't attempt to restore a clonezilla image on a drive of a different size, but anyway if it works this would basically be the same as a `cp -a`. And you'd have to use boot-repair anyway to be able to boot on your new system, so it looks a bit overkill to me.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to edit your /etc/fstab